# Azure Release Pipeline failed to download the template file from the given path

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, cicd

I'm creating a release pipeline and it should be picking up the ARM Templates from my built artifacts but it keeps giving the below error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

[image]

The way this has been configured is:

**1. Artifact is picked up from my build pipeline:**
[image]

**2. Build pipeline has successfully created the artifact:**
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyrLl.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k53JK.png]

**3. Artifacts are selected here**

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated

**EDIT:**

Have changed my CI pipeline to use PublishBuildArtifacts but not getting an error about 2MB limit:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do using PublishBuildArtifacts and linked ARM templates to overcome the 2MB issue:  learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/….

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your issue when i used the task `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` to publish aritfact in build pipeline.The same warning poped up when i selected `Override template parameters`. Then i changed the task to `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` and it worked.

RESULT

[image]

You can refer to this doc to understand the two types of publish artifact task:

[PublishBuildArtifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#usage)

[Publish Pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Here are suggestions to check:

1 check the type of publish artifact task in your build pipeline.

2 check your template that should follow Syntax and expressions in ARM templates

Comment: Thanks for looking at that. I'll try and implement the fix. However I simply copied the code from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements

Comment: For more understanding ARM template file, please refer to [structure and syntax of ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax)

Comment: Does it work for you? If helps, you could accept the answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.

Comment: Hi. Will pick this up after the Xmas holidays. Off work at the moment

Comment: Hi. I still can't get this working. Have changed my CI pipeline to use PublishBuildArtifacts:     PathtoPublish: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/$(PACKAGEJSONFOLDERNAME)/ArmTemplate' #replace with the package.json folder
    artifactname: 'ArmTemplates'. However not getting an error about 2MB download limit. Have updated my post

Comment: @Brian  Limit the size of your template to 2MB.You should simplify your template to avoid a large request, please refer to doc:[Resolve errors for job size exceeded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-job-size-exceeded?tabs=bicep)

Comment: I've found another solution using linked ARM templates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-linked-templates. I think this'll work

Comment: Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue. You can add an answer and [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).This will help other users who has the same issue.